# mysql consultas anidadas

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas una de convenios y otra de asociados, consulto la de convenios por que un convenio puede tener varios asociados obtengo todos los nit de los asociados y luego necesito obtener todo los nombres y apellidos de los asociados desde la tabla asociados intente con este query pero no funciono

```
       Select convenio.id_Convenio, convenio.nit_Fuente, convenio.sede, convenio.nit_asociado, convenio.nit_socio2 as nit2, convenio.nit_socio_3 as nit3, asociados.Nom_asociado as nom1, asociados.Apell_asociado as nom2 
From convenio

(SELECT asociados.Nom_asociado as soc2 , asociados.Apell_asociado as ap2,
convenio.nit_socio2
FROM convenio
LEFT JOIN asociados on convenio.nit_socio2 = nit2

)
(SELECT asociados.Nom_asociado as soc3 , asociados.Apell_asociado as ap3,
convenio.nit_socio2
FROM convenio
LEFT JOIN asociados on convenio.nit_socio_3 = nit3
)

LEFT JOIN asociados on convenio.nit_asociado = asociados.nit_asociado 
where convenio.id_Convenio like '4'
```

por favor necesito ayuda

Comment: Hola Jeferson. La pregunta no está clara. Lo más fácil para poder ayudarte es que 1) incluyas datos de ejemplo para ambas tablas en formato tabular 2) Describas cual es el error o el resultado erróneo de tu query cuando lo ejecutas con esos datos 3) Describas en formato tabular el resultado deseado.

Comment: hola sstan lo que pasa es que en convenio hay 3 nit diferentes nit_asociado, nit_socio2 , nit_socio_3 necesito los tres nit y luego ir  a la tabla de asociados y traer los 3 nombres y los 3 apellidos en la tabla asociados la columna donde esta el numero de nit es  nit_asociado y es un unique

Comment: saludos Jeferson, sería más sencillo si colocas un diagrama ER y datos de ejemplos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, creo que entendí. Necesitas hacerle join con la tabla `asociados` 3 veces, por lo que vas a necesitar asignarles aliases para distinguir los 3 joins:

```
Select c.id_Convenio,
       c.nit_Fuente,
       c.sede,
       c.nit_asociado,
       c.nit_socio2 as nit2,
       c.nit_socio_3 as nit3,
       a1.Nom_asociado as soc1,
       a1.Apell_asociado as ap1,
       a2.Nom_asociado as soc2,
       a2.Apell_asociado as ap2,
       a3.Nom_asociado as soc3,
       a3.Apell_asociado as ap3
From convenio c
left join asociados a1 on a1.nit_asociado = c.nit_asociado
left join asociados a2 on a2.nit_asociado = c.nit_socio2
left join asociados a3 on a3.nit_asociado = c.nit_socio_3
where c.id_Convenio like '4'
```

Nota aparte, la última condición `like '4'` es un poco rara. Si no vas a usar `%`, puedes simplemente usar el operador `=`:

```
where c.id_Convenio = '4'
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, voy a borrar la mía ya que es prácticamente un duplicado exacto

Comment: perfecto era tal cual muchas gracias y respecto al like lo estoy utilizando por que puede venir vacio y agregar otro campo al where

Comment: No son 2 tablas para que hacer 3 join

Comment: @OmarMiranda Porque es lo que se necesita hacer para obtener el resultado que quiere el op.

Comment: @Omar: Cierto que son 2 tablas, pero la información se encuentra en 4 registros distintos, 3 de los cuales están en la tabla `asociados`.